# What is the best way to do logging for REST method call?

Tags: java, spring

What is the best way to do logging for REST method call?

I tryed two ways to log the information of methods like input passed to the method, output of that method, if exception thrown - what exception, which class and method and exception line are logged.

Method1 : Using finally method

Method2 : Using Spring AOP

Which is the best way to do? Is there any other way we can do logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am here adding a point over ACV's  suggestion since what ever he has suggested are correct ,
1. AOP will be loose couple that give you more flexibility in terms of optional deployment ,
2.Your actual business logic and method will be remain neat & clean . no extra line would be appear there.
3.Could use your code for entire application even in other application too.

Answer (score 2):

`finally` is for exceptions. AOP looks good if you have many methods. Otherwise just add the LOG statements (in case you're using a logger framework like log4j) where you think you need them. AOP has a slight performance impact.

Comment: Hi ACV, thanks you for your answer. But what i don't understand is 'add the LOG statement where you think you need them'? I mean how should i do?

Comment: @SN in case you're using a logging framework , which you should